# Find matrix exponential

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

> Find the matrix exponential $e^{At}$ for $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0\\ 3& 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

I split this into the matrices

$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0\\ 0& 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$C=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0\\ 3& 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

And solved $e^{Bt}=\begin{pmatrix} e^t& 0\\ 0& e^t\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $e^{Ct}=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0\\ e^{3t}& 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$

I simply used power series for the exponential since $C^n=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0\\ 3^n& 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $B^n=\begin{pmatrix} 1^n& 0\\ 0& 1^n\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Then I computed $e^{Bt}e^{Ct}=e^{At}$

I got $e^{At}=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0\\ e^{4t}& 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$

But when I check this with a exponential calculator, it gives a solution $\begin{pmatrix} e^t& 0\\ 3e^t t& e^t\\ \end{pmatrix}$

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You have a wrong $e^{Ct}$. Notice $C^2 = 0$, one has $e^{Ct} = I + tC + \frac{t^2}{2}C^2 + \cdots = I + tC$.

Comment: @achillehui thanks I made the mistake of treating the power as the power of the exponents. I solved it properly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do directly from the matrix $A$, observe that
$$
\big(At\big)^n=\begin{pmatrix}
t^n & 0\\
3nt^n & t^n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then
$$
e^{At}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\big(At\big)^n}{n!}=\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{t^n}{n!} & 0\\
\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{3nt^n}{n!} & \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{t^n}{n!}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
e^t & 0 \\
3t\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} & e^t
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
e^t & 0 \\
3te^t & e^t
\end{pmatrix}
$$